# When does a void method return control?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I currently have an issue where a void method takes too long to return the control to the calling method. From benchmarks on my staging server it takes up to ~0.5 seconds to return.

This code has actually been in production for a long time now, but only recently did this slowdown happen. A particular method call that used to take less than 10 seconds now takes more than 30 seconds to complete.

If it's relevant I'm using `Spring` and `Hibernate` and this method is in a Service class. All it does is a trivial update that takes less than 0.001 second to execute.

Are there cases when void methods do not immediately return control to the calling method?

Answer (score 1):

> When does a void method return control?

As soon as the method finishes or an explicit `return` statement is executed.

> Are there cases when void methods do not immediately return control to
>   the calling method?

If you are using a framework such as Spring, there may pre/post task configured, which may be increasing the turnaround time.

Comment: I was thinking it might be something like that, but do you have any idea what particularly that could be?

Comment: Check if there is any AOP call (search for @Aspect in the code).

Comment: @Akolopez As Mike suggested look for AOP pointcut or similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your class is a proxy since it is managed by Spring or Hibernate. For example if you have annotated your class with @Service then your method is called in a transaction; therefore it may take some time. Hope it helped.

Comment: I guess I should add that this has been in production for a long time now and I've this slowdown just recently happened. Thanks.

Comment: You should check how long your SQL queries take (if the update accesses the db).